# Converting 12 hour time NSString to 24 hour NSDate object does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert a string for example “12:00 AM” to a date object with 24 hour format of time.
I get  NULL whenever i run following code to get date object. Changing locale to en_US_POSIX did not work as well.

```
NSString *TimeIn12hourFormat = @"12:00 am";
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[timeFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[timeFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate  *dateIn24HourFormat = [timeFormatter dateFromString:TimeIn12hourFormat];
NSLog(@"Time in 24 hour format : %@", dateIn24HourFormat);
```

If i am doing something wrong please point it out, otherwise guide me about the way i can do it. I have searched a lot, about this kind of string to date conversion but could not find such scenarios.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: What is output?  Why are you printing the date object directly using `NSLog()` instead of using a date formatter?  You don't appear to understand the important distinction here.

Comment: Your `dateFormat` does not match your string. "HH" is for 24 hours, missing how to read the "am" also.

Comment: Als setting the `TimeStyle` en `DateStyle` will have no effect if you are settings the `DateFormat` later,

Comment: @trojanfoe i am printing it through NSLog() to check date object for null value in console.

Comment: It will certainly do that, however once you start getting it working you'll be asking us why the date is `your_timezone - GMT` hours out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a letter "a" to your dateFormat. This means, that your time string has "AM" at the end.

```
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

`HH` is for 24 hour format where `hh` is 12 hour am/pm format.

Comment: Using this letter, gives "AM" in resulting string as well, which is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with following code, Thanks for all others contributors for their help.

```
NSString *TimeIn12hourFormat = @"12:00 am";
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[timeFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[timeFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDate  *dateIn24HourFormat = [timeFormatter dateFromString:TimeIn12hourFormat];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

TimeIn12hourFormat          = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:dateIn24HourFormat];
NSLog(@"Time in 24 hour format : %@", TimeIn12hourFormat);
```